# PCL6 renders PDF incorrectly

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

PCL6 is a tool from GhostScript, that generates PDF files by passing in text or other files.

I have a simple text file on Linux, that I am trying to convert to PDF using below

```
pcl6 -g7920x6120 -o Linux_output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite Linux_textfile
```

Each line pushes to the right in the PDF ( see attached outputs - http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696119
)

Where as the same command on Windows formats it correctly.

Request you to help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCL6 is a PCL interpreter from **Artifex**, Ghostscript is a PostScript interpreter, also from Artifex. So PCL6 is not a 'tool from Ghostscript'.

The PCL6 interpreter uses the same graphics library as the PostScript interpreter, and so they are able to share the same devices. While this means that the PCL6 interpreter is able to create PDF files, that is not its primary purpose.

PCL6 has graphics primitives which are not capable of being represented in PDF, so the PDF output is a 'best effort'.

Since you have already opened a bug report, there is no real point in this Stack Overflow question.

[later]

In fact the 'simple test file' turns out to be 2 different test files. The Linux test file has line endings with only a linefeed, the Windows test file has both carriage returns *and* linefeeds. The PCL page description language treats a linefeed as a linefeed and does not alter the x position, and a carriage return as a carriage return, which does not alter the y position.

So unsurprisingly, test files with different line endings result in different output.